# Objective-c - what does [super init] return?

Tags: objective-c

New to objective-c.  Wrote a code-snippet to better understand the init mechanism, and ended up with a few questions.

```
@implementation MyClass    
    -(id) init
    {
        if (self) {
            i = 5;
            NSLog(@"self before init - %@ %p i=%d",[self className], &self, i);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"self is null???");
        }

        id someClass = [super init];
        NSLog(@"the result of super-init - %@ %p",[someClass className], &someClass);

        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            NSLog(@"self after init - %@ %p %d",[self className], &self, i);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"self is null???");
        }

        return self;
    }
```

`i` is a private instance variable `int`.

Here is the result:

```
2012-12-14 18:01:26.403 Init[1621:303] self before init - MyClass 0x7fff5fbff848 i=5
2012-12-14 18:01:26.405 Init[1621:303] the result of super-init - MyClass 0x7fff5fbff838
2012-12-14 18:01:26.405 Init[1621:303] self after init - MyClass 0x7fff5fbff848 5
```

What really surprised me is that that someClass's class Name is `MyClass`.

- How does `NSObject` know to return the sub-classes instance (not just the type match, it is the exact same object)?

I'm aware that it is not good form to call `init` many times, and initialize instance variables before calling `init` but I was just experimenting.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `&someClass`--that returns the address of the reference, not what the reference contains. Use `someClass`.

Comment: `-init` is invoked on the result of `+[ <class> alloc ]`, which of course returns an (uninitialized) instance of <class>... `-init` doesn't do the allocation.

Comment: What @nielsbot says is true -- the addresses you're printing are the addresses of the pointer variables, not the addresses of the objects the variables point to.  This may be causing some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to use the standard schemen (more or less):

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Do initialization stuff
    }
 }
```

Your class subclasses some other class.  The call to `super init` runs the init routine of your superclass.  Without it your class is not properly initialized and may malfunction strangely.  (However, it's probably not wise to call `super init` twice, as this could have bad side-effects.)

There are cases where you would not call `super init`, but would instead call a version of `init` in your own class.  Basically, if you have `initWithJunk:` and `init`, you can have `initWithJunk:` call `[self init]` instead of `[super init]` so that the stuff that `self init` would do gets done and doesn't have to be reproduced in `initWithJunk:`.

This is especially critical if you write a "category" that adds an `init...` method to an existing class -- you must call some version of `[self init]` to assure that the base class's initializer runs.

Understand that the `super init` method is not (usually) *replacing* the existing instance with a new one, but rather is *initializing* instance fields in it that belong to the superclass.  The reason for receiving the "self" value back from the `super init` call is two-fold:

1. The init routine can return a `nil` in the event that some sort of error occurs.
2. In some (rare) special cases the init routine may replace the supplied instance with a different one (eg, a cached version).